# How to map Base64 value to a Long Integer in java?

Tags: java, unix, programming-languages, hmac

I am calculating HMAC-SHA256 of a given value. The result is a base64 string. What is the procedure to convert this to a Long Integer as I only want to extract the first 6 digits of the result?

Comment: 1) Decode Base64 to string.  2) Convert string (hexadecimal?) to a BigInteger.  3) Convert BigInteger to decimal string.  4) Use substring to get first 6 decimal digits. 5) Parse string as `Long`.

Comment: What do you mean by first six digits? First six bytes of the binary data? First six characters of hex representation of that binary data? First six decimal digits of the binary data treated as a large integer?

Comment: Thilo, for eg: the result is 189AeIB8719293==. The final value must be of the form 198765. How do I do that?